# Understanding JVM heap size (when using Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

There are a lot of questions about "how to increase heap size" here but I'd like to understand **how these settings actually influence memory consumption of a Java app** (Eclipse IDE in my case but I guess that doesn't matter).

My JVM starts up with these parameters:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

so I would expect that when something memory-demanding executes, the heap size will go up to 1024 MB. However, **I only see Eclipse allocating around 700-800 MB at most**.

[image: Eclipse heap size]

(if I understand the bar correctly, the yellow part is the current allocation, the whole bar is the max allocation and that there is some "marker" that I don't know what it is).

When I start a compilation of a large project, **I periodically see the yellow bar rising, reaching about 90% of the whole bar and then dropping back to about 200-300 MB**. That doesn't utilize the max allowed 1024MB, does it?

It'd be great if someone could explain this behavior to me and possibly how to change it.

BTW, my Eclipse is 64-bit version with 64-bit JVM if that matters (1024 limit should be OK for 32-bit too, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xmx is a hard limit. If the GC is able to clean objects / lower the mem consumption before hitting the limit the max, the max is not reached.

If you have some reason to require 1GB consumption of memory just set Xms and Xmx to the same size.